# Remove common word from list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

So, I am writing a code that will cross check every word in my list with a list of common words, if the word in my Alist is = to the common word it will be removed. I am trying to keep it basics to terms I learnt to not confuse my studying.

```
Alist = ["the", "baby", "is", "so", "happy"]
common = ["the", "so"]
for x in Alist:
    for i in common:
        if i == Alist[x]:
            Alist.remove(common[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list-comprehension to filter the words:

```py
Alist = ["the", "baby", "is", "so", "happy"]

# better convert the common words to set (for faster searching):
common = {"the", "so"}

Alist = [word for word in Alist if word not in common]
print(Alist)
```

Prints:

```
['baby', 'is', 'happy']
```